# hasfocus binding not working when assigned with a computed property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got an editable grid built with Knockout, which follows along the lines of the grid discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252503/knockout-custom-binding-handler).

I'd like `hasfocus` to be assigned with a computed observable (As opposed to what's been done on the above linked post, where `hasfocus` binding is assigned with the same observable as `visible`), but it doesn't work - the edited element is not being focused.

Here's my code (and here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3cajngd/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var viewModel = new Grid.ViewModel();
  viewModel.init();
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);   
});

ko.bindingHandlers.clickToEdit = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
     if (element.className == "editable") {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        span = document.createElement("span");
        var input = document.createElement("input");

        element.appendChild(span);
        element.appendChild(input);

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(span, {
          text: observable,
          visible: ko.computed(function() { return !viewModel.isEditState(); }),
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(input, {
          value: observable,
          visible: viewModel.isEditState,
          hasfocus: viewModel.shouldFocus, // this seems to not work (but it works if we assign it with isEditState)
        });
      }
    },
}

var Grid = {
  RowViewModel: function() {
     var self = this;
     self.district = ko.observable();
     self.team = ko.observable();
     self.factory = ko.observable();
     self.isEditState = ko.observable(false);
     self.shouldFocus = ko.computed(function() {
     return self.isEditState();
     });
    
     self.init = function (data) {
        self.district(data.District);
        self.team(data.Team);
        self.factory(data.Factory);
     }
    
     self.setEditState = function(){
        self.isEditState(!self.isEditState());
     } 
   },
 
  ViewModel: function() {
     var self = this;
     self.data = ko.observableArray();
     self.init = function() {
         var data = self.getData();
         self.data(data);
     }
     self.getData = function() {
       var data = [];
       var rows = [
         { District: "North", Team: "Jim", Factory: "Mars" },
         { District: "South", Team: "John", Factory: "Pluto" },
       ];
       rows.forEach(function (element, index) { 
         var row = new Grid.RowViewModel();
         row.init(element);
         data.push(row); 
       }); 

       return data;
     }
  },
}
```

```css
td, tr > th {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div class="grid-container">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" style="table-layout:fixed">
      <thead>
          <tr class="active">
            <th></th>
            <th>District</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            <th>Factory</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
          <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: district, clickToEdit: district"></td>
            <td class="editable" data-bind="clickToEdit: team"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: factory, clickToEdit: factory"></td>
          <td>
            <a href="#" data-bind="visible: !isEditState(), click: setEditState">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" data-bind="visible: isEditState(), click: setEditState">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The lines of interest are:

```
self.shouldFocus = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.isEditState();
});
```

Note: Though I merely use `self.isEditState()` here, I'd actually be using one or two more expressions, and thus the need to use a `computed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I can suggest a solution, I'd like to show you a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem. Note how much easier it is to see what's going on?

```js
const vm = {};

vm.visible = ko.observable(false);
vm.hasFocus = ko.computed(vm.visible);
vm.toggle = () => vm.visible(!vm.visible());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="visible: visible, hasFocus: hasFocus">
<button data-bind="click: toggle">toggle</button>
```

From this reconstruction I figured: could the problem be that the `visible` and `hasFocus` update are processed at once, not giving the DOM enough time to process both? After all, the browser cannot add focus to a hidden element...

Let's try to make the `hasFocus` computed `deferred`. A deferred computed runs on the end of the event loop, a bit like [`setImmediate(cb)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) or `setTimeout(cb, 0)` would.

```js
const vm = {};

vm.visible = ko.observable(false);
vm.hasFocus = ko.computed(vm.visible)
  .extend({ deferred: true });
vm.toggle = () => vm.visible(!vm.visible());

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="visible: visible, hasFocus: hasFocus">
<button data-bind="click: toggle">toggle</button>
```

**Success!** Now, knockout updates the visibility of the input, gives the DOM time to update, and *only then* adds the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `computed` to `pureComputed` and it will work.

You can see the pure function guidelines [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html#pure-computed-function-defined)

```
self.shouldFocus = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.isEditState();
 });
```

Comment: How can/would this fix the issue?